# In which port my pm2 process is running? (Linux)

Tags: linux, port, pm2

I want to know in which port my pm2 process is running, is there a way to know that with the name of my pm2 process?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a way, but first make sure that you are logging the port number in your app. If you're using Express.js, just do it the usual way:

```
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));
```

Then, in your Linux terminal, check the PM2 log for that process (`my-express-app` or whatever you called your PM2 process):

```
pm2 logs --lines 1 my-express-app
```

You can ommit `--lines 1` if you want, then it'll show you the last 15 lines of your log instead of just the last one.